# Node.js server went to both on data event and end event after java client sent https request

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, https

Code link: https://github.com/jason51806/java_client/tree/master

Client code:

```
public class SendClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

        }
    };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    /*
    * end of the fix
    */
    URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8001");

    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    //HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);

    JSONObject writeJsonObj = new JSONObject();

    //BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream()));
    //BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream()));
    writeJsonObj.put("msg","Hello server!");
    System.out.println(writeJsonObj.toString());
    printWriter.println(writeJsonObj);
    printWriter.flush();
    /*String text = writeJsonObj.toString();
    writer.write(text);
    writer.flush();*/

    while (true) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("--prepare to receive message");

        String line = null;

        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("read something from server");
        System.out.println(line);
        JSONObject readJsonObj = new JSONObject(line);

        System.out.println(readJsonObj.toString());

        if (readJsonObj.has("test")) {
            System.out.println("Send the second message to server");
            printWriter.println(writeJsonObj);
            printWriter.println();
            printWriter.flush();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
var https = require('https'); //Require module 
var fs = require('fs');

//varable declared
var Https_Options = null;   //Https server key and certificate
var Server = null;  //https server
var ServerInformation = null;   //Server's address and port
var ClientNumber = 0;   //current nunber of connected client
var num = 1;

Https_Options =
{
    key : fs.readFileSync('./hacksparrow-key.pem'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync('./hacksparrow-cert.pem'),
    allowHalfOpen : true
};

Server = https.createServer(Https_Options).listen(8001, "localhost", function() {
        ServerInformation = Server.address();
        console.log("Https server is running at "+ServerInformation.address+":"+ServerInformation.port);
    }    //end of https.createServer call back function
);    //end of https.createServer.listen

//Request listener, listening request event when client sending the request
//Call Back Function Description: "data", "close", "error" event

Server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    console.log("clients: "+ (ClientNumber++));
    //Data listener, litening is there any data sent from client
    //Call Back Function Description: The handler of "data" event
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var ServerDataObj = null;   //the data received from client and also send this Obj as response to client
        var testobj = {};

        testobj = 
        {
            'test' : num++
        };

        //ServerDataObj = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
        ServerDataObj = chunk.toString();
        console.log('server receive message' + ServerDataObj);
        res.write(JSON.stringify(testobj) + '\r\n');    //send back to client
        delete ServerDataObj;

    }    //end of event "data" call back function
    );    //end of event "data"

    req.on('end', function() {
            console.log("client end.");
        }    //end of event "end" call back function
    );  

    //listening close event
    //Call Back Function Description: Emmit whether the client socket close
    req.on('close', function() {
            console.log("client close.");
            --ClientNumber;
        }    //end of event "close" call back function
    );    //end of event "close"

    //Error listener, 
    //Call Back Function Description: if error happen, catch & print
    req.on('error', function(err) {
            console.error("req: "+err);
        }    //end of event "error" call back function
    );    //end of event "error"

}    //end of event "request" call back function
);    //end of event "request"
```

I use PrintWiter  to send request on my Java client code.

The node.js server received request data successfully but it triggered the end handler that causes server can't receive the request from client anymore.

I also try BufferedWriter and DataOutputStream to send my request to server, but they both have the same problem.

- Is there any way to not trigger the end handler on server and keep the client send data continually?
- Or any other ways to send message between Java client and node.js server on https?

Comment: and what have you tried? Post your code please

Comment: you may want to investigate websockets.

Comment: Hey, try to ask questions scoped narrowly enough that you could post the relevant code here without overwhelming people. This is way too broad and demanding based on how you posted it. People have limited time and patience to dig into other people's problems. This site is for solving targeted technical questions. Please clock the help link at the top and see how to ask a question.

Comment: I'm sorry about my first post. If there is any unclear place on my question, please let me know. Thank you for correcting my bad asking habit. ^_^